# Как создать deb пакет?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, deb

Пишу на  python3  под Ubuntu, хочу создать deb пакет, подскажите как, или где есть доступная информация?

Comment: [кратко](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/DebianBuildPackages) [подробно](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/)

Comment: Размыленно както но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Зависит что в пакете. Вот [шаги для простого скрипта](https://askubuntu.com/q/399552/3712). Чтобы руками директории не создавать, можно [шаблон для cookiecutter использовать](https://github.com/Springerle/dh-virtualenv-mold). Инструменты разные есть: [stdeb, fpm, vdist](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2vn1yz/what_is_the_best_way_to_create_deb_package_from/)

Comment: [py2deb](https://py2deb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html) выглядит к неплохая из недавних попыток на эту тему.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Для того, кто не понимает как устроены .deb пакеты эта задача может оказаться неподъемной, как бы просто не было написано в гайдах.

Первое, что у вас должно быть в наличии - это работающий `setup.py`, чтобы ваше приложение могло корректно собрать все необходимые файлы и зависимости, где надо скомпилироваться и т.д. Нет `setup` - нет пакета.

Второе - ваш самый лучший друг отныне - это [dh-virtualenv](https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv). dh - значит DebHelper. helper'ы - это специальные утилиты, помогающие собрать вам пакет. Эта штука прочитает ваш [`requirements`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files), скачает нужную версию Python, скачает все зависимости, скомпилирует опять-таки все, что нужно и ваше приложение окажется мало того, что в пакете, так еще и автоматически в [`virtualenv`](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). То есть ваше приложение развернется из пакета уже в изолированной обертке и вы можете быть уверены, что оно никому ничего не сломает, не переставит системный Python, не понаставит лишних библиотек и независимо. Это так круто, что даже сложно описать не задыхаясь. Подключить `dh-virtualenv` легко.

Третье - создайте в корне проекта каталог с именем `debian` - это служебный каталог со служебными файлами. Об их назначении и подробностях вы сможете прочитать в соответствующих руководствах, здесь я приведу примеры таких файлов:

`rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv

override_dh_virtualenv:
    dh_virtualenv --python /usr/bin/python3
```

Подключает `dh-virtualenv` и указывает, что собираемся с Py3. По умолчанию `dh-virtualenv` последней версии поместит ваши файлы при установке в `/opt/venvs/<packagename>`, но это зависит от версии, читайте readme. Этот путь можно [переопределить](https://dh-virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-usage).

`control`:

```
Source: MY_COOL_PACKAGE
Section: python
X-Python3-Version: >= 3.3
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Choo Choo <choochoo@train.swag>
Build-Depends: debhelper-compat (= 13), python, dh-virtualenv (>= 0.8), python3-setuptools
Standards-Version: 4.5.0

Package: MY_COOL_PACKAGE
Architecture: all
Depends: ${python:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, postgresql-client, libpq-dev, postgresql-contrib, python3-all, python3-dev, python3-setuptools, python3-pip, libxml2-dev, libxslt1-dev, zlib1g-dev
Description: Таки посмотрите на зависимости, подставьте те, которые нужны вам
```

В этом, да и Makefile обратите внимание на наличие и количество пробелов - вся сборка это ОЧЕНЬ бюрократизированный процесс, не там поставите пробел (или поставите 5 вместо четырех) и долго не будете понимать, в чем дело. С пробелами нужно быть крайне внимательным, читайте в руководствах как конкретно разделяются секции и команды. Обратите внимание, в Makefile команды в рецептах начинаются с табуляции, а не с четырёх пробелов, как их заменяет Stack Overflow. Исправьте это вручную после копирования. Также включите в вашем редакторе подсветку пробельных символов, чтобы распознать смесь пробелов и табуляции.

`changelog`: тут вам поможет утилита `dch`. Пускайте `man dch` и вам там пояснят за смену версий, утилита простая. Можно жахнуть `dch -i`, чтобы увеличить версию на 1, заполнить список изменений и информацию о контрибьютере. Получится как-то так:

```
MY_COOL_PACKAGE (0.5.1) experimental; urgency=medium

  * Пофиксил бажную страницу

 -- Choo Choo <choochoo@train.swag>  Mon, 10 Apr 2017 17:24:45 +0300
```

`conffiles`: `/etc/MY_COOL_PACKAGE/my_config.ini` - необходимость в этом файле возникает, если у приложения есть конфиги, в понимании этого слова с позиции dpkg (https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg-dev/deb-conffiles.5.en.html). Больше про конфиги: https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/

После этого ваше приложение выглядит как-то примерно так:

```
my_app:
-- .git
-- sources
---- debian/
------ changelog
------ compat
------ control
------ files
-------- rules
---- source_files/
---- requirements.txt
---- setup.py
-- .gitignore
-- readme.txt
```

Когда все сделано, все файлы созданы - выполняете команду [`dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.ru.html#completebuild). Кто-то предпочитает не пользоваться низкоуровневым dpkg, а вместо него использует дебилд - `debuild`.

Либо dpkg, либо дебилд, если все сделано верно, соберут вам пакет и несколько других файлов, они нас пока не касаются - вас интересует только .deb файл. Это обычный архив, и вы можете посмотреть его, чтобы убедиться, что все на месте.

Если все на месте, то не спешите радоваться, потому что перед тем, как посылать этот пакет в архив, вам нужно его проверить - за это отвечает утилита `lintian` - она проверит ваш пакет и выдаст вердикт. Если пакет некачественный, то перед установкой `dpkg` будет ругаться (и всем будет говорить, что пакет некачественный - стыдно), однако, после подтверждения даже некачественный пакет можно установить.

Также нужно отметить, что приведенное "руководство" - довольно простой пример для маленького приложения. Наверняка вам потребуется изучить, как вставить `pre-install`, `post-install` скрипты (например, для миграций), не раз прочитать руководство на предмет остальных служебных файлов и параметров сборки, коих тьма.

Comment: Будем дерзать, а что делать?)

Comment: @m9_psy, а в каком руководстве описаны свойства файла `debian/configs`, о котором вы рассказываете? Не ясно, за что он отвечает.

Comment: @mymedia, не уверен, возможно это были толстые пальцы, подредактировал исходя из контекста на `conffiles`

Comment: @m9_psy, ручной conffiles давно считается устаревшим и больше не используется - https://manpages.ubuntu.com/dh_installdeb

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, вам нужен либо [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb), либо пакет [devscripts](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/DebianBuildPackages) (можно установить командой `sudo apt install devscripts`)