# Как засунуть пакет pip, например psycopg2, в deb пакет?

Tags: python, pip, пакет, deb

возможно ли засунуть пакет pip, например psycopg2, в deb пакет?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать deb пакет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653384/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-deb-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82)

Comment: а смысл какой в этом? вы его вместе с питоном засунуть хотите? а зависимости как?

Comment: Зависимости тоже в деб пакет. Кстати есть deb helper на эту тему

Answer (score 0):

Для сборки библиотек питона в python-pkgname существуют дебхелперы - скрипты из dh-python.

https://debian-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dh_python.html
Документация довольно обширна чтоб копипастить её сюда.

dh-virtualenv [Как создать deb пакет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653384/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-deb-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82) тоже интересная штука, но не будет использовать системные библиотеки и интерпретатор.